# "row" and "row-reverse" gray/invalid in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

I, and many of my classmates, are experiencing an issue with flexbox **CSS** where `row` and `row-reverse` are not being accepted as valid arguments for `flex-direction`. I am primarily using Atom, and `row` and `row-reverse` just appear grayed out when I try to use them for "flex-direction". "column" and `column-reverse` work just fine. Here is the **CSS** for the code I am currently working with (the issue is at the end). This isn't the only time I have had this problem:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content-label {
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.article-container {
 height: 90%;
 width: 100%;
}

.content-one, .content-two, .content-three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.content-one {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.content-two {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.content-three {
  background-color: #0f0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

Here is the **HTML** as I have it right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Responsive CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css"     type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" type="text/css"     media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <p class="content-label">header</p>
    </header>
    <section class="article-container">
      <article class="content-one">
        <p class="content-label">one</p>
      </article>
        <article class="content-two">
          <p class="content-label">two</p>
        </article>
        <article class="content-three">
          <p class="content-label">three</p>
        </article>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS looks fine. btw, `flex-direction` default value is `row`, you don't need to explicitly set it,

Comment: what about using flex-flow  ? is that also in issue in your tests ? flex-direction:row; is meant to be the defaut value; does the flex boxmodel being still trigered or is not at all ? Your code does not show any clue of your issue, only justify-content seems to be updated on mediaquerie here

Comment: Could you post your markup as well

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying that `row` is the default value. I still, however, have the issue if I change `row` to `row-reverse`.

Comment: Are you trying to make each article appear in a row? You will need to add the flex display to the section `.article-container`. The only flexboxes are the direct children. So in your case, when adding it to the body, only the header and the section are flexboxes.

Comment: I did not know the flex only applied to direct children, so thank you so much!